# Update JList after removing all the elements from the model(AbstractListModel)

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a JList where each element holds some special data. So I have implemented AbstractListModel for the JList.

Everything works great when I have one or more elements in the list.

But, does not work in the scenario below:

- Jlist is already instantiated with some elements.
- I need to remove all the elements from the list.
- I do not have the JList object(Component) accessible in the model, so can't call repaint().

I cannot call fire***() methods of AbstractListModel since it throws OutOfIndexException.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `"Any suggestions?"` -- Yes, find out why your code is throwing the exception by doing some debugging and then fix the error. The real question in my mind is why you are not posting the results of your debugging experiments since the answer all hinges on this. Else I doubt that we can help you.

Comment: Because I am calling fireContentsChanged(this, 0,0)..which will look for 0th element in the list which does not exist. I know the cause but not the solution.

Comment: That's the wrong method to call when removing elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state:

> Because I am calling fireContentsChanged(this, 0,0)..which will look for 0th element in the list which does not exist. I know the cause but not the solution.

Don't call `fireContentsChanged(...)` when removing items. Call `fireIntervalRemoved(...)` instead. Also as an aside, you should never have to call `repaint()` in this situation. Changing the state of the model and then notifying the model's listeners through a call to the proper `fireXXX(...)` method is all that should be done.